# Setting x-axis label range while auto-scaling y in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm finding it really difficult to achieve something that feels like it should be really simple, using matplotlib. I have a time series of 1000 data points, recorded 10s apart.
I want to plot them, so that the x-axis range is correctly labelled from 0 to 10,000s. I want the y-axis values to be chosen automatically.

Whatever I try, I can't seem to get matplotlib to display any labels on the x axis other than the number of datapoints in the array (i.e. 0-1000). I have tried:

plotting twice. First letting it autoscale, then calling plt.axis() to retrieve the x and y limits, and then storing them for a second call of plt.axis([a,b,c,d]). It just plotted 0-1000. Somehow it just ignored me and reverted to 0-1000.

I tried this:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)  

ax.xaxis.set_data_interval(0, 10000)
```

also

```
plt.xlim(0, 10000)
```

to no avail, as well as many other things I've now deleted and forgotten. I can't believe I've somehow wasted hours on this now!

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Edit: I was asked for a minimal example - here are two that illustrate the two results that I have found,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tseries=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
plt.plot(tseries)
ax = plt.subplot(111)  
ax.xaxis.set_data_interval(0, 10000)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This one is just ignored

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tseries=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
plt.plot(tseries)
plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

And this one squashes all the data, keeping it in the 0-10 range of the plot.

All methods I have tried have produced one of the two results above

Basically I just want the first plot with the axes of the second.

Comment: How are you plotting the values? `ax.plot(data)` or `ax.plot(x, y)`? Because it sounds like you're doing the former, but you want the latter as `ax.plot(range(0, 10000, 10), data)`.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: @FHTMitchell That gives me "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (10001,)"

Comment: @DavidG I've added a couple! cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but this should be as simple as creating a X-series that contains the time values/labels you want. No need to do any limiting of the axis range:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

values = random.sample(range(0,1000), 1000)
times = np.arange(len(values)) * 10

# alternatively:
# times = np.arange(0, len(values)*10, 10)

plt.plot(times, values)
```

[image]

`values` has your 1000 data points. you need to create another array that contains the times associated with each of your values. In your original question you didn't specify an X array, so it was just plotting your values against index (0-9)

Because you know that each value recording happened 10 seconds apart, it should be as simple as generating a 1000 item list with the values 0-1000, and then multiplying each item by 10 to get the actual "recorded" times

Comment: You're not misunderstanding the question, merely underestimating my lack of competence with matplotlib ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution that works. There's probably a better way.

```
x = np.arange(0.0, total_time, total_time/len(tseries))
y = np.array(tseries)
plt.plot(x.flatten(),y.flatten())
```

Edit:

This turned out sometimes fail, saying the lengths of x and y were not the same.
I added this hack to prevent that:

```
if len(x)!=len(y):
    l=min(len(x),len(y))
    x=x[:l]
    y=y[:l]
```

I guess it's caused by rounding errors in the "total_time/len(tseries" term when creating x.
Edit2: Mr. T has pointed out below that np.linspace() can be used to avoid the rounding error.

Comment: Use [`np.linspace()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to avoid rounding errors.